# Error occurred while doing bulk copy from temp table to entity table-Conversion overflows. DIXF AX 2012 R3

Tags: dynamics-ax-2012-r2, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I am getting below error for one of my entities when i am copying from Source to Staging table.

Error occurred while doing bulk copy from temp table to entity table-Conversion overflows.

When I am checking in debugger when executing below line its going to catch
[s]    \Classes\DMFGenerateSSISPackage\generateStagingData                                                   613
returnRec  = dmfEntityProxy.MigrateEntity(helper);

Not able to find out whats the exact cause. All variables are having loaded with data in this method. Not sure how to resolve this.

Anyone found similar issue before??? AX 2012 R3, DIXF

Comment: What's your application version? In my version (6.3.5000.133, CU12) the line from your stack trace is on line 318, not 613. Does this occur with only one entity (which one) or several? Is it a custom or standard entity?

Comment: We are using ax 2012 r2. 6.2.3xxxx.1861.  This is happening only with this entity. Its a custom entity.

Comment: Then why do you reference R3 in the question title, question and tags? Could you tell us more about the custom entity or provide an .xpo? Chances are the issue is not with DIXF, but with the custom entity.

Comment: Can you provide an email so can send xpo? i am not sure how to add it here.